# QML - How to send/pass variable from one qml file to other qml file

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

How to send a variable, or signal between qml files ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MChCG.png

1. Mainwindow -> create a component Item2.qml
2. MainWindow -> create a component item1.qml
3. item1.qml  -> create a component Item3.qml
4. Item3.qml  -> change/send variable or signal to ItemII.qml(is created in mainwindow) - How ?

Someone could write a small example ?

Comment: Do you want the above said items to be created on the fly(dynamic object creation)?

Comment: Item is normally created in code, not dynamically. I change widget through visible: false/true. Its similar to Ribbon UI. I have mainwindow. In mainwindow i have two items: one is ribbon(other qml file), two is live preview(other qml file). In ribbon i create a item(from other qml file). In this item i have a combobox or something like this. This combobox is sending signal/or change variable in live preview(mainwindow).

Comment: @Programmer, could you do an example of a dynamically instantiated object passing to a regular QML?  I am creating a popup window and I want to pass a value selected from that window back to the creating object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Example code:

Item1.qml

```
//Item 1
import QtQuick 2.1

Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 100
    color:"red"
    Text{
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        font.pixelSize: 16
        text:"Item1"
        width:parent.width
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
        color:"white"
    }
}
```

Item2.qml

```
//Item 2
import QtQuick 2.1

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    color:"blue"        
    Text{
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        font.pixelSize: 16
        text:"Item2"
        color:"white"
    }
}
```

Item3.qml

```
//Item 3
import QtQuick 2.1

Rectangle {
    id:item3
    width: item3Area.pressed?90:100
    height: item3Area.pressed?90:100
    color:"green"
    signal superAwesomeSignal(string txt)
    Text{
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        font.pixelSize: 16
        text:"Item3"
        color:"white"
    }
    MouseArea{
        id:item3Area
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked:item3.superAwesomeSignal("Hello, from Item 3 ")
    }
}
```

Main.qml

```
//Main.qml
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Item1{
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        Item3{
            id:item3
            anchors.top: parent.top
            onSuperAwesomeSignal: item2.item3SignalReceived(txt)
        }
    }
    Item2{
        id:item2
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        signal item3SignalReceived(string txt)
        onItem3SignalReceived:console.debug(txt)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you think you got the required answer, please upvote the answer apart from accepting the answer. Doing this will mark the question as [Solved].Thanks.